# Pandas data frame fill null values with index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where for one column I want to fill null values with the index value. What is the best way of doing this?

Say my dataframe looks like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d=pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['Num','Name'], data=[[1,'Andrew'], [2, np.nan], [3, 'Chris']])
>>> print d

  Num    Name
A    1  Andrew
B    2     NaN
C    3   Chris
```

I can use the following line of code to get what I'm looking for:

```
d['Name'][d['Name'].isnull()]=d.index
```

However, I get the following warning: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

I imagine it'd be better to do this either using fillna or loc, but I can't figure out how to do this with either. I have tried the following:

```
>>> d['Name']=d['Name'].fillna(d.index)

>>> d.loc[d['Name'].isnull()]=d.index
```

Any suggestions on which is the best option?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMO you should use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna), as the `Index` type is not an acceptable data type for the fill value you need to pass a series. `Index` has a [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html#pandas.Index.to_series) method:

```
In [13]:
d=pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['Num','Name'], data=[[1,'Andrew'], [2, np.nan], [3, 'Chris']])
d['Name']=d['Name'].fillna(d.index.to_series())
d

Out[13]:
   Num    Name
A    1  Andrew
B    2       B
C    3   Chris
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `.loc` in this situation like this:

```
d.loc[d['Name'].isnull(), 'Name'] = d.loc[d['Name'].isnull()].index
```